# Bob has no less than 50 $2 coins in a bag. After organizing it he finds there are no remainders whether it's 6 or 8 coins per row.

Tags: education

> Bob has no less than 50 $2 coins in a bag. After organizing them, he finds that there are no remainders whether it's 6 or 8 coins per row. What is the minimum total value of the coins?

Saw it on TV and the answer is $144. I can't seem to solve it algebraically. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This question is very vague. Are there any more specific details?

Comment: why not 48 dollars which is 2 dollars multiplied by LCM of 6 and 8?

Comment: Sorry, hopefull it's more clear now. I can't provide any more context as that's pretty much all the information provided on the show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can be arranged in a row of 6 and 8 without a remained, then 6 and 8 is a factor of the number of coins. The lowest common multiple of 6 and 8 is 24, however 24 is lower than the minimum of 50 coins required to be in a bag. Through trial and error you can find that the smallest number with both 6 and 8 as a factor over 50 is 72. If you have 72 2 dollar coins, then the total value is $144, your answer.

Comment: Thanks JC12! Gosh so simple, I over complicated this trying to solve this with algebra....

Comment: The lowest common multiple of 6 and 8 is *24*. So we need the minimum multiple of 24 that's over 50, which is 72.